# Как заменить [color="тут пользовательский цвет"]тут пользовательский текст[/color] на <p style="color:тут пользовательский цвет;">тут текст</p>

Tags: javascript, php, html, scss

Как заменить [color="тут пользовательский цвет"]тут пользовательский текст[/color] на тут текст

Я это использую в своей системе комментариев, это чтоб можно было пользователям менять цвет комментария, например человек пишет в textarea это:
[color="red]это красный текст[/color], а это чёрный текст
Отправляет комментарий
И видит его в списке уже таким:
Это красный текст, а это чёрный 
Причём,"это красный текст" будет красным цветом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это решается с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$str = '[color="red"]это красный текст[/color]';

$patt = '~\[color="([^"]+)"\](.+?)\[/color\]~';
$repl = '<p style="color:$1">$2</p>';

$str = preg_replace($patt, $repl, $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: Спасибо, я проверю

Comment: $message =str_replace(array_keys($arrEmoji),array_values($arrEmoji), $message);
$patt = '~\[color="([^"]+)"\](.+?)\[/color\]~'; $repl = '<p style="color:$1">$2</p>'; $message=str_replace($patt,$repl,$message); Почему-то ваш код не роботает если его использовать с str_replace

Comment: А если без то вобщем роботает